# linq query Sum and group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linqpad

I need help with a linq query, SQL is

```
select usuario2.PkUsuarioId, sum (evento.EventoHora) as total
from TUsuario as usuario, TUsuario as usuario2, TEvento as evento
where usuario.PkUsuarioId = 2 
and usuario.PkUsuarioId = usuario2.Fkusuario_UsuarioAdminId 
and usuario2.PkUsuarioId = evento.FkEvento_UsuarioId
group by (usuario2.PkUsuarioId)
```

result:

[image]

i need this SQL in Linq query, i tried this Linq query

```
from usuario in TUsuario
from usuario2 in TUsuario
from evento in TEvento
where usuario.PkUsuarioId == 2
&& usuario.PkUsuarioId == usuario2.FkUsuario_UsuarioAdminId
&& usuario2.PkUsuarioId == evento.FkEvento_UsuarioId
group usuario2 by usuario2.PkUsuarioId into value
select new {value.Key, suma = TEvento.Sum(x => x.EventoHora)}
```

result:

[image]

why the linq query  throws 50 in all rows?

Comment: You probably should use joins or if possible check for navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are summing the field, not your group.

Change `TEvento.Sum(x => x.EventoHora)` to value.Sum(x => x.EventoHora) <s>`value.Select(x => x.EventoHora).Sum()`</s>

**Edit:** Thanks @juharr

Comment: Or just `value.Sum(x => x.EventoHora)`.

Comment: if I change to "suma = value.Sum(x => x.EventoHora)",  the compiler show me this error : "The name 'value' does not exist in the current context". what does it mean 'value'. @JB06

Comment: @ernestopetit That doesn't make any sense, because it would complain about `value.Key` as well.

Comment: `value` is the name assigned to the group in the query

Answer (score 0):

The problems are that you are summing over the entire table instead of the groups and you are grouping the `usuario2` instead of the `evento`. Also you should try to use navigation properties if possible.  It should look something like this depending on your Entities.

```
from usuario in TUsuario
from usuario2 in usuario.TUsuarios
from evento in usuario2.TEventos
where usuario.PkUsuarioId == 2
group evento by usuario2.PkUsuarioId into grp
select new 
{
    grp.Key, 
    suma = grp.Sum(x => x.EventoHora)
}
```